# JupyterLabでcumlのインストールをしたい

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

JupyterLab 3.3.2です。cuml のサポートベクタマシンを使いたくて以下のコードを実行したところ、エラーが表示されました (エラー #1とする)。

**実行したコード:**

```
from cuml.svm import SVR
import cuml
print('RAPIDS version',cuml.__version__)
```

**エラー #1:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from cuml.svm import SVR
      2 import cuml
      3 print('RAPIDS version',cuml.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuml'
```

インストールすればいいんだと考え、次に `conda install cuml` を実行したところ、以下のエラーが表示されました（エラー #2 とする）。

**エラー #2**

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working...
done Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve.
Retrying with flexible solve. Collecting package metadata
(repodata.json): ...working... done Solving environment: ...working...
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
current channels:

  - cuml

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
you're looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

https://anaconda.org で「cuml」と検索して表示されたリストの一番上の rapid/[**cuml**](https://anaconda.org/rapidsai/cuml) を開き、提示されたインストールのためのコマンドを全て試しましたがエラー #2が表示されるだけです。カーネルの再起動は試しました。
JupyterLabでcumlをインストールする方法をお教えください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JupyterLabでどうこうというよりも、使っているOSの問題だと思われます。

エラーメッセージの`Current channels:`を見ると使っているOSが64bit Windowsのようですが、[Anaconda.orgの該当ページ](https://anaconda.org/rapidsai/cuml)を見ると`linux-64`と`linux-aarch64`しかサポートされていません。

開発元のページを見ても同様で、使うためにはLinux系のシステムが必要と書いてあります。
Windowsは近い将来にサポートする可能性があるということですが、それは低いでしょうね。
[Welcome to cuML’s documentation!](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/)

> An installation requirement for cuML is that your system must be Linux-like. Support for Windows is possible in the near future.

[probableとpossibleの使い方【可能性を表す表現】](https://vtakeharu.com/2020/01/29/post-1129/)

> possibleよりもprobableの方が可能性的には高くて、probableが70%、possibleが30％くらいのイメージです。

Windows用の非公式なバイナリを用意・配布しているサイトにも`cuml`はありません。
[Archived: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

同じ開発元の現在のメインプロジェクトらしい`cudf`のインストール手順ではもう少し詳しく出ています。こちらでは、Windowsで使うためにはWindows11・WSL2・Ubuntu 20.04が必要と書いてあります。(関連部分だけ抜粋)
[Getting Started|RAPIDS](https://rapids.ai/start.html)

> SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS
> OS: One of the following OS versions:
> Windows 11 using WSL2 [See separate install guide >>](https://rapids.ai/wsl2.html)

[RAPIDS + WSL2|RAPIDS](https://rapids.ai/wsl2.html)

> PREREQUISITES
> OS: Windows 11.
> WSL Version: WSL2. WSL1 is not supported.
> WSL2 Instance: Ubuntu 20.04 instance for WSL2.

他にGPUとCUDA関連も必要なようですが、それらは上記開発元ページで確かめてください。